# Salesfore Rest API Integration Error: invalid_operation_with_expired_password

Tags: apex, rest-api, integration, query, oauth2

I have created an Oauth app in Salesforce and with the details (Client id, client secret) I was able to establish the connection using SOAPUI/Postman. i.e I have received access_token in the response and instance URL.

I have used the above access_token received in the response to perform the below "GET" request and worked like a charm.

Endpoint: https://penn--pforce.cs44.my.salesforce.com

**Resource: /services/data/v42.0/sobjects/**

Header: Authorization: Bearer access_token

But when I am performing the below GET request, I am seeing the below error. The password is not expired and it's weird why it would give error in one scenario and not in the other.

Endpoint: https://penn--pforce.cs44.my.salesforce.com

**Resource: /services/data/v42.0/query/?q=SELECT+name+from+Account**

Header: Authorization: Bearer xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

Error:

```
[{ "message": "The users password has expired, you must call 
     SetPassword before attempting any other API operations",
     "errorCode": "INVALID_OPERATION_WITH_EXPIRED_PASSWORD"
 }]
```

Please let me know if there's something that I need to do.

Thanks

Comment: If you can add the required code snippets that might helpful to give more insight

Comment: I haven't added any code. It's just a basic Get request with access token given by salesforce.